# What happens to the electric field of dipoles and in the electric field of capacitors when we introduce a dielectric in a capacitor?

Tags: electric-fields, capacitance, dielectric

I am trying to understand the concept of [dielectric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric) materials.

I know that when we insert a dielectric inside of a [capacitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor)  with constant voltage the electric field of the capacitor does not change but what happens in the electric field of dipoles

I found this equation:

$$ E_{local} = \frac{1}{3} \ (\varepsilon_{r} + 2) \ E_{ext} $$

https://chat.openai.com/share/88abd4d0-3239-4965-adec-ce3b9dd0db06

Is this right ?

Why is the local electric field increased, if it has the opposite direction of the capacitor's electric field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is wrong, or if you, wish not quite right... You can find the correct formula in, for example, Jackson: Classical Electrodynamics (3rd edition), Sect 4.4 p158. Equation 4.55, according to which the internal electric field intensity $\mathbf E_{in}$ of a sphere of homogeneous dielectric in external field $\mathbf E_{ext}$
$$ \mathbf E_{in}= \frac{3}{\epsilon_r+2} \mathbf E_{ext}$$
and as you expected $E_{in} < E_{ext}$ because $\epsilon_r >1$ for all real material. Note that for a *sphere* $\mathbf E_{in}$ is *parallel* with $\mathbf E_{ext}$!